# investigate DatastorageMetrics for ignite configurations

Tags: ignite

I share our ignite DatastorgateMetrics for persistence store configurations, pls kindly discuss about this config/metrics. Are there any warning metrics need to be considered?

our cluster suddently degraded performance

[DatastorageMetrics in JMX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KADnD.png)

Comment: This is too vague to answer. We'd need to know more about what you're doing, your configuration, how performance is degraded, etc.